# Prove that $\dim \ker(T)$ is either $n$ or $n-1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T\colon V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear transformation.

If $\dim(V)=n$, then $N(T)=n-1$ or $n$ .

I tried proving this with rank nullity theorem but I got nowhere. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's the possible dimension of the image?

Comment: Hint : $\text{Im}\,T \subseteq \mathbb{R}\implies \text{dim Im}T\leq 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Either $\;T=0\;$ or $\;T\;$ is surjective, so either $\;\dim\text{Im}\,T=0\;$ or $\;\dim\text{Im}\,T=1\;$ , and now use the dimensions' theorem (=the rank-nullity theorem).